# How to get default language of termSet

Tags: 2013, language, term-set

I want to get the language of termSet from term group in which it was written. for example if termSet language is English it should return English and if its language is Swedish, it should return Swedish Programatically using server side API.

Note: In my Term Group, some termSets are in English and some termSets are in Swedish. Need sample code to get idea?

Comment: check this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10869/how-to-get-all-the-term-labels-for-a-particular-language-us.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get all language specific labels provided they are create using correct lcid. See below:

```
Swedish Label
term.CreateLabel("hej", 1053, true);

English Label
term.CreateLabel("hello", 1033, true);

term.GetAllLabels(1053); //Get all Swedish labels on a term
```

Also look at    CreateTerm(String, Int32, Guid) method which creates a new Term.The name is the default Label for the specified LCID. (Inherited from TermSetItem.)